# developer hasn't given you access to this app flutter google sign in

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a flutter mobile app. I'm getting this error when I'm trying to log into my google account. I have setup firebase correctly and generated SHA keys and place it o firebase properly. what should I do now. appreciate your help on this.

```
 onPressed: () async {
       await authClass.googleSignIn(context);
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create a google signIn.dart class

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

GoogleSignInAccount? _user;

GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

Future googleLogin() async {
try {
  final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  if (googleUser == null) return;
  _user = googleUser;

  final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
} catch (e) {}
notifyListeners();
}

Future logout() async {
await googleSignIn.disconnect();
FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
}
}
```

Create your button to login, then call the google sign in

```
Widget buildUpgradeButton() => ButtonWidget(
    text: 'Login',
    onClicked: () {
      final provider =
          Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false);
      provider.googleLogin();
    });
```

Lastly manage the login state

```
  class signedIn extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const LoggedIn();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(child: Text("Something Went Wrong!"));
          } else {
            return const ProfilePage();
          }
        }),
  );
 }
```